# Chrome Extension Notifications Not Appearing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I've been trying to develop a chrome extension that creates notifications after certain periods of time. I've been using both `chrome.alarms` and `chrome.notifications` to accomplish this, but I cannot get notifications to appear, even when creating them from the console. I also don't get any errors from `runtime.lastError` in the callback. I do know for certain that the alarm listener and callback are being executed.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "notifications",
  "version": "0.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["notifications.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "permissions": [
    "alarms",
    "storage", 
    "notifications"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "mascot48.png"
  ]
}
```

**notifications.js**

```
function resetTimer(id, minutes) {
  chrome.alarms.create(id,{delayInMinutes: minutes});
}
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener((alarm) => {
  console.log('alarm!');
  chrome.notifications.create('reminder', {
    type: 'basic',
    iconUrl: 'mascot48.png',
    title: 'Dont forget!',
    message: 'You have things to do'
  }, function(notificationId) {
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
  });
});
```

Is there anything clear that I'm getting wrong?

EDIT: For clarity, notifications.js is my events page, the popup page is the one that runs the code to start the alarms.

Comment: I do not see the place where do you run a timer. There are only a function declaration and event subscription.

Comment: @Deliaz notifications.js is my events page. The popup page runs the reset timer code every time the settings are changed from the popup.

Comment: Could you please share complete code, which can reproduce the problem?